# rmarkdown: specify manually pandoc path?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a rmarkdown document that I render regularly with `rmarkdown::render`

It works fine on my computer (Windows) as I have RStudio installed, and it has setup automatically the path to pandoc.

However when I try to run it on my server (outside RStudio), it fails with error that pandoc is not found.

How can I set up manually the path the pandoc from my script? Without changing the configuration on the server.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="PATH_TO_MY_PANDOC_BIN/binaries/pandoc/pandoc.exe")
```

Comment: Just thought I'd comment here for people working in environments where editing the path is frowned upon - in a pinch you could just drop the pandoc.exe file in the same directory as your rmarkdown files and you can get it to run and render properly.

Comment: Amazing comment, saved my life

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to set the system path for pandoc (Windows 10 instructions):
1. In the Start menu, search for "Edit the system environment variables"
2. At this point, Windows may ask you for username + password (for a user with permission to change system settings)
3. Click "Environment Variables" button
4. In the *lower* part of the window (*System variables*), select the line with "Path" and click Edit
5. Add the path to the folder where pandoc.exe is, but *not* including "pandoc.exe" or a slash at the end

Comment: Is there a similar solution that does not involve admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

`Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="PATH_TO_MY_PANDOC_BIN/binaries/pandoc/pandoc.exe")`

That is actually almost correct, just omit the *.exe files, write the path only up to folder contain pandoc.exe

like this :
`Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="PATH_TO_MY_PANDOC_BIN/binaries/pandoc")`

i believe this doesn't require admin rights