# Way to define pandoc file path within the scope of a single r script file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm having an issue with an rmarkdown report project that I'm trying to deploy at work.

On my work computer I have administrative rights, so I have been able to configure all of my system paths accordingly for pandoc, and the project runs perfectly on my local machine. I've moved the whole project to a network drive, and made sure everything points to the required dependencies correctly, but now I'm hung up on getting pandoc to be correctly found on the network drive.

The desired goal is that R, and the project's required libraries/dependencies can be run from this network drive, so that any user with access to the network drive will be able to generate a report.

I've been digging and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672864/rmarkdown-specify-manually-pandoc-path) is the closest post related to my question.

I'm trying to avoid having to install and configure pandoc on all of the local machines for each intended user. My hope is that there's a way to specify the file path to the pandoc binaries through the `render()` function? Or an obscure pandoc arg?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: AFAIK a version of pandoc also comes bundles with RStudio... or rmarkdown?

Comment: It does, and worked great during development. But the intended users won't have rstudio on their machines, and we won't have an rstudio server running anywhere in our network either.

Comment: I don't know about R, but pandoc provides statically linked binaries that you should be able to place on your network share and run.